# How to plot 2 subplots that share the same x-axis

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

So currently i have a `scatterplot` and a `kdeplot` that i used seaborn library to plot out.
[image: .]
[image: .]
Here is how i plotted the graphs:

```py
# plot a graph to see the zipcodes vs the density
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
sns.kdeplot(king['zipcode'], shade=True, legend=False)
plt.xlabel('Zipcode')
plt.ylabel('Density')
```

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
sns.scatterplot(king['zipcode'],king['price'])
```

But when i try to do a subplot, my kdeplot seems to be gone:
[image: .]
I tried to do in such a way:

```py
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
sns.kdeplot(king['zipcode'], shade=True, legend=False)
sns.scatterplot(king['zipcode'],king['price'])
```

Is it possible to render both graph in subplots properly?

Comment: Pass the axes object to the plotting function. e.g. `sns.kdeplot(ax=axarr[0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep! Credits to @DavidG, i managed to plot out the subplots properly. So i added the axes object into the respective graphs. Here it goes.

```py
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(16,8), sharex=True)
sns.kdeplot(king['zipcode'], shade=True, legend=False,ax=axarr[0])
axarr[0].set_ylabel('Density')
sns.scatterplot(x=king['zipcode'],y=king['price'],ax=axarr[1])
plt.show()
```

And it results in this:
[image: .]