# How to alter the hue legend?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataset that represents male and female in binary. Males are represented as 0 while females are represented as 1. What i hope to do is to change 0 to Male, and 1 to Female in the plot legend. I tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63188083/how-to-plot-2-subplots-that-share-the-same-x-axis), but it didn't work out.

It gives me an error message that looks like this:

```py
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-b3c99d4311ab> in <module>
     23 # plot the legend
     24 plt.legend()
---> 25 legend = g._legend
     26 new_labels = ['Female', 'Male']
     27 for t, l in zip(legend.texts, new_labels): t.set_text(l)

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute '_legend'
```

This is how my currrent code looks like:

```py
## store them in different variable names
X = salary['years']
y = salary['salary']
g = salary['gender']

# prepare the scatterplot
sns.set()
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
g = sns.scatterplot(x=salary.years, y=salary.salary, data=salary, hue='gender')

# equations of the models
model1 = 50 + 2.776962335386217*X
model2 = 60.019802 + 2.214645*X
model3_male = 60.014922 + 2.179305*X + 1.040140*1
model3_female = 60.014922 + 2.179305*X + 1.040140*0

# plot the scatterplots
plt.plot(X, model1, color='r', label='Model 1')
plt.plot(X, model2, color='g', label='Model 2')
plt.plot(X, model3_male, color='b', label='Model 3(Male)')
plt.plot(X, model3_female, color='y', label='Model 3(Female)')

# plot the legend
plt.legend()
legend = g._legend
new_labels = ['Female', 'Male']
for t, l in zip(legend.texts, new_labels): t.set_text(l)

# set the title
plt.title('Scatterplot of salary and model fits')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your data, so I generate some by my own:

```
gender salary years
male 40000 1
male 32000 2
male 45000 3
male 54000 4
female 72000 5
female 62000 6
female 92000 7
female 55000 8
female 35000 9
female 48000 10
```

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


salary = pd.read_csv("1.csv", delim_whitespace=True)

print(salary)

X = salary['years']
y = salary['salary']
g = salary['gender']


# prepare the scatterplot
sns.set()
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
g = sns.scatterplot(x=salary.years, y=salary.salary, data=salary, hue='gender')

# equations of the models
model1 = 50 + 2.776962335386217*X
model2 = 60.019802 + 2.214645*X
model3_male = 60.014922 + 2.179305*X + 1.040140*1
model3_female = 60.014922 + 2.179305*X + 1.040140*0

# plot the scatterplots
plt.plot(X, model1, color='r', label='Model 1')
plt.plot(X, model2, color='g', label='Model 2')
plt.plot(X, model3_male, color='b', label='Model 3(Male)')
plt.plot(X, model3_female, color='y', label='Model 3(Female)')

# plot the legend
plt.legend()

# set the title
plt.title('Scatterplot of salary and model fits')

plt.show()
```

[image]

It works fine. So I guess values in your `gender` column are `0` or `1`. In that case, you can do the following before `g = salary['gender']` to replace `0` with `male` and `1` with `female`:

```py
salary['gender'] = salary['gender'].map({1: 'female', 0: 'male'})
```

Back to your error:

```
---> 25 legend = g._legend
     26 new_labels = ['Female', 'Male']
     27 for t, l in zip(legend.texts, new_labels): t.set_text(l)

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute '_legend'
```

`g` returned by [`sns.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) is class [`matplotlib.axes.Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes). To get lengend object from it, you need to use `ax.get_legend()` or `ax.legend()` rather than `ax._legend`. You can follow the officail [Legend guide documentation](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html).

```py
legend = g.legend()

new_labels = ['Female', 'Male']
for t, l in zip(legend.texts[-2:], new_labels): t.set_text(l)
```